Total lag is negative in Kafka
I have a Kafka in my server, I had tow consumer group on common topics, I deleted all topics and producer create them immediately, After that message count and total lag is  negative number and when I consumer again and again I read message from not currect index,

I try remove topics again, But don't resolve my problem.

Can you try with kafka-consumer-groups.sh CLI instead? Maybe it's a UI bug

Also, group offsets are stored separately from topic data, so consumer groups won't be automatically reset when you delete topics. Consumers should use  auto.offset.reset property, in that case
